# Jump over an object in a global search.

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I am creating a global search in a ngx-datatable like this :

```
filterDatatable(event) {
const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
this.temp = this.tempOrig.filter(function(item) {
  let result = false;
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
      const value = !!item[key] && item[key];
      if (!!value && value.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) > -1) {
          result = true;
          // break;
          }
      });
  return result;
  });
}
```

My search is done on data from a webservice I mapped. However, the first element of the data I am mapping is an `INT` type. Then my function `value.toLowerCase()` can't work on this number.
Can we, just for the search, jump over this first element ? Or must I mapped my item differently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if the item has the `toLowerCase` method:

```
if (!!value && value.toLowerCase && value.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) > -1)
```